# How to solve this proof by contradiction?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

So far this is what I have: [image]

Now I am wondering how I can get a contradiction. I sub'd b = ax into the first equation and saw nothing that was contradictory ..

Comment: $b=ax$ so $bc = a(xc)$.  But $xc \in \mathbb Z$.  So let $n = xc$ we get $bc = an$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. A direct contradiction of $bc \ne an$ for any $n \in \mathbb Z$.... (I'm not loving your text BTW)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$b = ax,x\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Multiplying by $c$, we get:$$bc = axc$$
Now we select an integer $m=xc$.$$bc=am$$
So $$a\mid bc$$ which leads to a contradiction.